# iOS- Add keychain item to safari for HTTP-Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari

Is it possibe to add keychain items to safari within my app so that it will automatically use the information in the keychain item to pass a Basic Authentication challenge?

My problem at the moment is that I try to install an app with itms-services and [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:] and the ipa is secured with basic authentication. So when I try to install the app I get a challenge. But I don´t want the user to type in the credentials. I want safari to automatically do this instead.

I already looked at [MCSMInternetKeychainItem](https://github.com/ObjColumnist/MCSMKeychainItem) but I am not really sure if it can help me here.